# Position Tkinter grid Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I was doing some tests and there is something that I don't understand with grid.

This is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, bg='blue',width=200,height=200)
frame.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="news")

frame2 = Frame(root, bg='red',width=200,height=200)
frame2.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky="news")

frame3 = Frame(root, bg='green',width=200,height=200)
frame3.grid(column=2,row=0, sticky="news")

frame4 = Frame(frame, bg='yellow',width=100,height=100)
frame4.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="news")

frame4 = Frame(frame, bg='orange',width=100,height=100)
frame4.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="news")

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to have the orange and the yellow square inside my blue box. But as you can see when you run the code the blue box disappear behind the yellow and the orange. How can I solve this problem to get :

[image]

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma Yes, but I want the blue to be as the picture show above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue frame is shrinking to the content of its children. You can avoid that by calling `grid_propagate`:

```
frame = Frame(root, bg='blue', width=200, height=200)
frame.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="news")
frame.grid_propagate(0)
```

Result:
[image]